# Numprint decimal part without separation

Tags: typography, numprint

I know the question has an answer using `siunitx` but I am wondering about a possible solution with `numprint`. I would like to have three digits separation before the decimal separator but not after it. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\begin{document}
Raw:
1234567.78907

Numprint English:
\numprint{1234567.78907}

\selectlanguage{french}
Numprint French:
\numprint{1234567.78907}

\selectlanguage{english}
Desired output in English:
1,234,567.78907

\selectlanguage{french}
Desired output in French:
1\,234\,567{,}78907
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `numprint` has not changed since 2012...

Comment: @projetmbc Yes. Indeed, I am now using `siunitx` but I have old docs in which I use `numprint`.

Comment: Update this documents using a script written in Python for example could be a better solution.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes. Laziness on my side without doubt. Fortunately, I have a simple solution now.

Answer (score 6):

The command `\npthousandthpartsep{separator}` allows to suppress the French and English separators.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\begin{document}
    Raw:
    1234567.78907

    \npthousandthpartsep{}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Numprint English:
    \numprint{1234567.78907}
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    \npthousandthpartsep{}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Numprint French:
    \numprint{1234567.78907}\bigskip
    
    \selectlanguage{english}
    Desired output in English:
    1,234,567.78907
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    Desired output in French:
    1\,234\,567{,}78907
\end{document}
```

The global style  can be changed adding

```
\renewcommand{\npstyle<language>}{\npthousandthpartsep{}}
```

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\renewcommand{\npstyleenglish}{%
     \npthousandsep{,}%
    \npthousandthpartsep{}}% added <<<

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\npstylefrench}{\npthousandthpartsep{}}   % added <<< 
    
    Raw:
    1234567.78907
    
    Numprint English:
    \numprint{1234567.78907}
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    Numprint French:
    \numprint{1234567.78907}\bigskip
    
    \selectlanguage{english}
    Desired output in English:
    1,234,567.78907
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    Desired output in French:
    1\,234\,567{,}78907
\end{document}
```

The macro  `\g@addto@macro`
can be used to append commands to an existing `\npstyle<language>` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\npstyleenglish{%
    \npthousandthpartsep{}% added to english style<<<<
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\npstylefrench{%
    \npthousandthpartsep{}% added to french style <<<<
}%
\makeatother

    
    Raw:
    1234567.78907
    
    Numprint English:
    \numprint{1234567.78907}
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    Numprint French:
    \numprint{1234567.78907}\bigskip
    
    \selectlanguage{english}
    Desired output in English:
    1,234,567.78907
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    Desired output in French:
    1\,234\,567{,}78907
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed: I overlooked this in the doc!

Comment: And thanks again for the new details.